# Poketmine Server Error being ban when anybody dies

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android, hosting

I recently started a poketmine Server but there was a major problem whenever anybody dies he/she is banned from the server. I was unable to report at poketmine so I reported here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your server is set to Hardcore mode, in which case it is functioning as intended.  Assuming Pocket Edition's servers work basically the same way as the PC game, you should change the "hardcore=true" setting in your server properties to "hardcore=false".

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. The funniest part was even I the server owner was getting baned.